# Powerbuilder 12.5.2 Classic consume WCF Service. How configure a custom binding

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, powerbuilder

I have a problem with a Powerbuilder Classic 12 application that consume a WCF .Net 4.0 service with a custom binding.

The application generate the client correctly, but it don't execute any operation because the cliente recieve the following exception:

> Client found response content type of 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="http://tempuri.org/0";boundary="uuid:a74e39ad-b275-4b45-b2cd-f30668604483+id=11";start-info="application/soap+xml"', but expected 'application/soap+xml'.

I need configure a custom binding with MTOM encoding in the Powerbuilder Classic 12 application client to execute the operations.

A test client in .Net 4.0 defines the following binding configuration:

```
 <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="basicEndpoint" receiveTimeout="01:03:00" sendTimeout="01:03:00">
                <mtomMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    messageVersion="Soap12" maxBufferSize="12582912" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="12582912"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </mtomMessageEncoding>
                <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="12582912"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="12582912" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="12582912" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
```

How i configure a custom binding in PowerBuilder 12 Classic?

Best Regards